# How to set Background image in 4 inch iOS 7 and iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, fullscreen

I trying to set full background image on this below screen but i got for below output for 4 inch screen. i thought some status bar issue on ios 6

My question is how set to background image properly.

**Consider the image as full white color image with footer**

My code

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iPhone568ImageNamed(@"test.png")]];


#define isPhone568 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
#define iPhone568ImageNamed(image) (isPhone568 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h.%@", [image stringByDeletingPathExtension], [image pathExtension]] : image)
#define iPhone568Image(image) ([UIImage imageNamed:iPhone568ImageNamed(image)])
```

Note: don't consider the button design/alignment

**iOS 6 - 4 inch screen**
[image: iOS 6 - 4 inch screen]

**iOS 7 - 4 inch screen**

[image]

Comment: What's the question?  What do the white-backgrounded images add to your question?

Comment: are you useing autolayout??

Comment: no i'm not using autolayout

Comment: @meaning-matters  full white color image with footer

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with the `UIView` of your view controller (as it seems from `self.view. backgroundColor`):

- On iOS 6 the view's frame starts at y==20 (so after the status bar).
- On iOS 7 however, the view starts at the top of the screen, so at y==0 and underneath the status bar.

The view's height is therefore 20 point more on iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 use

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

iOS 6 use

```
    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```